# How to retrieve, in Python, row and column numbers of the elements in a matrix that match a certain value?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

The problem is actually very simple, but I can't translate it in Python, because I'm new to the language.

I have a dataframe of boolean values "True" and "False" and I need a list of the coordinates of the false elements:

I need to do this on a series of matrices that are generated automatically with varying number of rows and columns, but always with Boolean values.

For example, I have a matrix like this:

```
    0       1       2
0   TRUE    FALSE   FALSE
1   TRUE    FALSE   TRUE
2   TRUE    TRUE    TRUE
3   FALSE   TRUE    TRUE
4   TRUE    TRUE    TRUE
5   TRUE    TRUE    TRUE
6   TRUE    TRUE    TRUE
7   TRUE    TRUE    TRUE
8   TRUE    TRUE    TRUE
```

And I'm looking to retrieve a list like [(0,1),(0,2),(1,1),(3,0)]

I was trying to solve this problem with pandas (so do consider the matrix as a "pd.DataFrame" object) and numpy but I'm new to the language and can't seem to understand how the functions work and utilize them properly.

Comment: can you please format the matrix example as it is difficult to understand

Comment: It's my first question, I don't how to format it.

Comment: Here's the [manual](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for formatting.

Comment: Thank you, sir, very much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Method 1:

Using `np.argwhere`

```
np.argwhere(~df.values )

array([[0, 1],
       [0, 2],
       [1, 1],
       [3, 0]], dtype=int64)
```

#### Method 2:

*Edit after @Scott Boston comment*

We can use `np.where` for this and after that `zip` the two arrays to get the coordinations:

```
list(zip(*np.where(~df)))

[(0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 1), (3, 0)]
```

**Explanation**

`np.where` gives us two arrays, first one is the row index, second is the column index.

```
np.where(~df)

(array([0, 0, 1, 3], dtype=int64), array([1, 2, 1, 0], dtype=int64))
```

So if we `zip` these arrays and convert it to a list, we get our wanted output.

Comment: `list(zip(*np.where(~df)))` use unpacking +1

Comment: Thanks for the tip, edited answer accordingly @ScottBoston

Answer (score 2):

You can stack the dataframe and use boolean indexing:

```
t=df.stack()
t[~t].index.values
```

Output:

```
array([(0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 1), (3, 0)], dtype=object)
```