# How can I get coordinates of a 2D matrix consisting of only 0s and 1s

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, tuples, png

I have a binarized mask, consisting of only 1s and 0s. I want to get all of the locations in the image for the 0s so that I can compare it to the image background.

I am loading the masks by:

```
import PIL
from PIL import ImageOps, Image
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import load_img
from numpy import asarray

mask_path = '/Users/mshah/Downloads/8_24_Test2/Masks/3_Agar_Site_3_cp_masks.png'


loaded_mask = PIL.ImageOps.autocontrast(load_img(mask_path))
mask_array = asarray(loaded_mask)

zero_array = np.where(mask_array == 0)
```

This gives me a tuple with 2 indexes which I don't understand how to use. `shape` for `mask_array` is `(160, 160)` and `dtype` is `uint8`.

Note: the reason that I am using autocontrast instead of just Image.open is because Image.open doesn't work with binarized PNGs (at least the way I'm using).

Any suggestions/help?

EDIT: I found the answer, it is posted below

Comment: So, what exactly do you want to get in the end?

Comment: A list of locations in the array where there is a 0.

Comment: Can you give an example of the desired output?

Comment: I don't really have an example, it is why I am trying this, but like [row x column, row x column, etc]

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer via [How to retrieve, in Python, row and column numbers of the elements in a matrix that match a certain value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56599843/how-to-retrieve-in-python-row-and-column-numbers-of-the-elements-in-a-matrix-t).

I created an `np.ones` array with size `(160, 160)` and then subtracted the mask image from the ones array to get an array that contained 1s for where the background was.

```
shape = mask_array.shape

ones_array = np.ones(shape, dtype='uint8')

sub_array = ones_array - mask_array
```

Then I used `list(zip(*np.where(sub_array == 1)))` to create a list of where the coordinates are by zipping the x and y's together.